# How to filter queryset for serializing a nested serializer using instance in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My serializers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from diagnosisApp.models import Question, Option


class OptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Option
        fields = ('id', 'content')


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    content = serializers.CharField()
    options = OptionSerializer(
        Option.objects.filter(optiongroup__question=**insert instance value here**).distinct(),
        many=True
        )
```

I'm trying to create a nested OptionSerializer inside QuestionSerializer but I need to filter the queryset based on the question instance which will be passed during initialization in this section: `optiongroup__question=**insert instance value here**`. How do I do this?

P.S: Please don't tell me to use ModelSerializer or SerializerMethodField because options is not directly related to Question and the options field needs to be writable.

My models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Question(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        blank=False,
        default='',
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

class OptionGroup(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey(
        'Question',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default='',
        )

    options = models.ManyToManyField('Option')

    next_question = models.ForeignKey(
        'Question',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='+',
        null=True, blank=True
        )


class Option(models.Model):

    content = models.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        blank=False,
        default='',
        unique=True
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

P.P.S: Also please don't tell me to nest OptionGroup and then nest Option inside OptionGroup because I do not want to display OptionGroup at all only the related options.

Comment: Can you show yours models ?

Comment: @Wilfried Edited. Please check.

Comment: When I saw your PS and PPS, I suggest you to get `OptionGroup` into your `QuestionSerializer` and override `to_representation()` to get `Options` from this `OptionGroup` and display only options related to your `Question`.